# mysql- insert multiple groups of data a single column

Tags: mysql

I have a table named as `mytable` where it has  column named `a_column`.currently it is `null` valued and it has 100 rows. I just need to know how to set the value of  first 50 rows as `ABC` and rest 50 rows as `XYZ`. I have tried to use below queries  but i was unsuccessful. kindly suggest me the query.

```
    UPDATE mytable
    SET    a_column= 'ABC'; 

INSERT INTO table (mytable) VALUES ("ABC/XYZ")
```

chamath

Comment: You will need to write loop using cursor, and in it, count 50 times 'Abc' and 50 times 'xyz'. Or use temp table with AUTO_INCREMENT and then update `mytable` with matching temp table records where identity column < or >= 51

Comment: if you only have 2 groups (more than 2 and is dynamic is a different story.) and they are only divided by "/" maybe you could try the UPDATE and limit the update to 50. First update will be the ABC and the second update will be the XYZ just always include the null condition to the where clause so it doesn't overwrite the previous update or use the offset. Or lastly maybe 1 update with @variable.

Comment: Does mytable have some way of knowing the first 50 rows - such as an auto-increment id column?

Comment: yes it has a field  called 'auto_increment_id',which counts from 1 to 100.

Answer (score -1):

You can use following query to do that.

UPDATE mytable
    SET    a_column= (CASE WHEN id > 50 THEN 'XYZ' ELSE 'ABC' END);

Comment: This requires certain assumptions which are highly unlikely to be true.